# add new font to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

I am trying to add this font http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html to my visual studio.  i have downloaded it and added it to the Windows/fonts directory. restarted the computer and yet i still cant find it on the fonts and colors settings.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GDI+ doesn't play nicely with OpenType fonts, you will need to find a TTF version, how about this one: http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/inconsolata/?r=fffda675769720a297f4d239e7065f751bbe655f